# CentOS and the IBM x3850 M2

Tags: centos6, ibm

Im kinda new to this sort of stuff so its worth asking for some advice on the matter.
I have recently purchased one second hand IBM x3850 M2 however am slightly confused when it comes to installing the OS.
When i install it using the disk it displays the error "Cannot find default configuration file" and the internal usb refuses to load any OS i try to use on it and just displays the word 'Error' 
(Im trying to install CentOS 6.8),

Answer (score 0):

You can use Centos 6.8 bootable USB drive, and change boot sequence properly in BIOS to USB Drive.

[Use this link to download rufus and make bootable USB using Centos[For windows]](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

And for Linux use `dd` command like this:

```
dd if=/path/to/centos6.8.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Comment: Remember that that command will delete everything from `sdb`, so make sure it is the correct drive before running the command.